# How to pass foreign key id to form? or link form to a foriegn key value DJango

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to auto populate my form Student field with the name Carl Park. In short I want my form to use to automatically use the Object ID instead of having to manually select the name Carl Park from the student field drop down menu.

How do I automatically link my Model Form to a foriegn key ID and have the form auto populate based on that value.

Here is my current form, my models.py forms.py views.py and HTML

[image]

```
 #models
class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    room = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    bio = models.TextField()
    

class Student(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey('Teacher', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
  

class Student_Performance(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey('Student', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    behavior_grade = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    
    
    
#form
class StudentPerfromanceForm(ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Student_Performance
        fields = ( "name", "behavior_grade")

        
#view
def student_details(request, id):
    obj  = get_object_or_404(Student,pk=id)
    
    form = StudentPerfromanceForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StudentPerfromanceForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return all_students_list(request) #pass success message

    return render(request, 'class_roster/student_details.html', {'obj':obj, 'reviewForm':form})



#HTML
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{reviewForm.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Review">
</form>
```

Comment: Add a get parameter to your link i.e. when you click on the link for a certain students details the url would be like student/1 where 1 is the pk of the student instead of student/

Answer (score 0):

I want to more code informations.

anyway if you want set student automatically use object_id,

try

```py
objects.get(query)
```

ex) ModelClassName.objects.get(pk=1)

Comment: I need it to work dynamically from a details page. The one student is just an example. I am hoping to be able to click a student and from a detail view, record notes about selected student.